How can I use XSLT3 with SaxonJS to transform JSON to XML?
I find it very hard to find good example on the internet to transform a simple json to xml using xslt3 with the SaxonJS library.
I found the following:
https://www.saxonica.com/papers/xmlprague-2016mhk.pdf
But I can not really follow how that works.
I've tried running:
npm i xslt3
./node_modules/.bin/xslt3 -json:test.json -xsl:test.xsl -o:test.xml -t && cat test.xml

With example JSON:
{
    "a": 1
}

With XSL:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                version="3.0">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <base>
            <a>
                <xsl:value-of select="/map/number"/>
            </a>
        </base>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>

But this leads to an empty XML.
Also changing the select to:
    <xsl:template match=".">
        <base>
            <a>{?a}</a>
        </base>
    </xsl:template>

as suggested by other items don't seem to work. Not sure if this is related to the latest version. I'm using version 2.7.0

It is not clear which XSLT format/result you want but if you use the -json option then the JSON is represented as an XDM 3.1/XPath 3.1 map and/or array and subsequently your second approach using the lookup operator ? seems like the right approach.
With complete context:
XSLT
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="3.0"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
  expand-text="yes">

  <xsl:template match=".">
      <base>
          <a>{?a}</a>
      </base>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>

transforms JSON
{
    "a": 1
}

into XML
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><base><a>1</a></base>

Works fine for me in my fiddle as well as from the command line:

As for using json-to-xml, in that case I would start with the initial template named xsl:initial-template, use a global parameter for the JSON file name (or URI in general), read the JSON as a string with unparsed-text and then convert to XML, pushing the result to your templates that transform the XML representation of the JSON to the XML format you want. Keep in mind that the result elements of json-to-xml are in the XPath function namespace.
Example stylesheet:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                xpath-default-namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
                version="3.0"
                exclude-result-prefixes="#all">

    <xsl:param name="json-uri" as="xs:string">sample1.json</xsl:param>

    <xsl:template name="xsl:initial-template">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="$json-uri => unparsed-text() => json-to-xml()"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <base>
            <a>
                <xsl:value-of select="/map/number[@key = 'a']"/>
            </a>
        </base>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>

Example run:


Thank you! This is indeed working. Is there some way I can map it with json-to-xml() that in my mapping I can use the xml way of mapping it?

@Mark, if you want to use json-to-xml I would suggest not to use the -json option but to declare a global parameter <xsl:param name="json-uri" as="xs:string">file:/home/user/sample.json</xsl:param>, then to have a global named template <xsl:template name="xsl:initial-template"><xsl:apply-templates select="$json-uri => unparsed-text() => json-to-xml()"/></xsl:template> and, on the command line, use -it to ensure SaxonJS or other Saxon versions start with that template. You will need to add the other templates to process the result of json-to-xml to the XSLT, of course.

I believe this exactly what we are looking for. I've tried to run this xslt3 -it:init.xsl -xsl:test.xsl -o:test.xml with your example but this gives an error: Unknown initial template Q{}init.xsl. Maybe I misunderstood something? Could you elaborate on how I could get your example working?

Provide the XSLT doc, as you do, with -xsl, for the it option use no argument, just the plain -it.
